# R segfaults when starting R by opening a source file

Tags: r, macos, macos-sierra

My R.app (R version 3.3.2, R.app GUI 1.68 (7288) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) on macOS Sierra is odd.

When I start `R.app` by clicking the app icon, I have no problems.

But if I start `R.app` by double-clicking a source file (e.g., `test.R`) in Finder.app or if I type `open test.R` in Terminal.app, I get a segfault error ("memory not mapped").

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
> 
Selection:
```

It is OK if `R.app` is already running when `test.R` is opened.

When `R.app` segfaults, I am sometimes lucky to have control and can close the app normally. But at other times, `R.app` halts with the spinning wheel appearing, and I have to Force-Quit the app. After I force-quit `R.app`, the next time I start `R.app`, I am permanently stuck (with `R.app` halting trying to open `test.R` as soon as I restart `R.app`), in which case I solve the problem by starting `R` from `Terminal` by typing `/Applications/R.app/Contents/MacOS/R`.

What would be the problem?

Comment: I read the R-SIG-Mac mailing list and there are several reports of intermittent problems with the MacGUI, but so far they have not be reproducible by the Mac fork maintainers. It possible you would contribute to the solution by posting your example (including the code of test.R) to tht mailing list. That is the recommended location for bug reports, not SO.

Comment: Thanks, 42-. I was wondering where to ask. I will ask R-SIG-Mac.

Comment: I've read threads in R-SIG-Mac in the mean time and found: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2016-December/012124.html